# Can anyone help in identifying this plant that I bought some days ago?

Tags: identification, houseplants

We bought this plant some days ago, but are unable to identify it correctly. Earlier I thought it to be Eucalyptus but it doesn't look like one.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the many faces of Euphorbia strikes again. To me, this is [Euphorbia (Pedilanthus) tithymaloides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_tithymaloides). Perhaps the dwarf cultivar "nana" form which is more compact.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a ZZ Plant (Zamioculcas zamiifolia).

According to the product info page from http://www.logees.com, the ZZ plant was named Houseplant of the Year and has the following description,

> The ZZ plant is ideal for low light conditions where few other plants thrive. The dark green, shiny, alternate leaves grow on stout, fleshy stalks that are swollen at the base.
>
> Growing from an underground rhizome that stores water, the ZZ Plant is extremely tolerant to drought and low light conditions.
>
> This indestructible houseplant has an almost prehistoric appearance! 
>       It’s an excellent container plant for interiorscapes and was named “Houseplant of the Year” for its ease of growing and unusual beauty.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a correct identification. Zamioculcas has smooth stems unlike this one that has segments. Also the stems of Zamioculcas has a swelling at the base and the leaves are quite shiny.